# Starting god through rails server / passenger?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rake, monitoring, god

Following situation:

I have a server and some rake tasks which should run the whole time, f.e.:

```
# email_sender.rake (except only)
while true
  fetch all mail entries.each do |mail|
     mail.deliver
  end
end
```

or another rake task

```
# update_market.rake (except only)
while true
  Market.fetch_exchange_rate!
  sleep 1
end
```

For starting and stopping these rake tasks i use the god gem and it works quite well.
But one thing isn't clear to me: Can i start my god server within rails with an initializer? f.e.

```
# rails_root/config/initializers/start_god.rb
system 'god -c /www/rails_root/config/god.config'
```

I tried it in my development environment and as i wanted, the server runs even if i exit the rails server.

But is there any caveat when running this in production mode?

Thanks for your opinion!

p.s. I DONT WANT TO USE CRON! This solution is perfect to me and i dont want to change to another scheduler/queue/background job system!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a Rails initializer probably isn't the best way to start that process, it's not really what they were intended for. Have you looked into Foreman with Procfile? It might suit you.

http://ddollar.github.com/foreman/

Comment: Hmm... And can you tell my why it isnt the best way to start god with initializers? And do you mean that i shall start god with foreman?

Comment: Rails initializers are designed to setup the "environment" for the Rails application. Putting your god startup call in there tightly copules the startup of your application to the startup of god. And it doesn't take care of shutting god down when needed, or restarting/reloading. Think of it like the MVC pattern. Can the View layer call directly into the database to get information? Sure it /can/ but that doesn't mean its good design to do so. And yes, basically Foreman would run call the "start" functions for both your Rails application and god process.

Answer (score 0):

What are you using for deploying your application? If you are using Capistrano for example, you should be using Capistrano to start and reload god (in your production environment).

For development, foreman is a very convenient tool to manage these processes, as ctcherry mentioned. You can also [export a god config file](https://github.com/otherinbox/foreman-export-god/) directly from your Profile.